# Spanner ParseDDL doesn't like when I use SELECT STRUCT in the Subquery

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I'm trying to create a Spanner View using spanner go client.

when I use spanner/spansql.ParseDDL.

```
SELECT
 ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(firstName, lastName, phone_number)
    ) AS user_info
```

Error: got "(" while expecting ")"

But if i just copy and paste this into Spanner Studio in google cloud console, no problem

`go version go1.20.4 darwin/arm64`

spanner client version: v1.59.0

I tried different spanner client versions and no luck.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the open source SQL parsers that is used by `spanner/spansql.ParseDDL`. I see that you have already opened an issue in the GitHub repository here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/9622

I would recommend following up on that bug.